# How to vertically center a div in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started using Bootstrap and I would like to have a vertically centered div.
A div (not the content) that has **equal margin on top and bottom.** Something I can achieve by using `position:absolute;` but I want to achieve it the Bootstrap way.

This is my markup so far:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="home" class="well well-lg col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer luctus nisl non tortor hendrerit, ultrices volutpat velit lobortis. Donec blandit non ligula sed eleifend. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ac libero id elit pellentesque bibendum. Morbi lacinia ut ante in semper. Quisque eu urna aliquam, ultrices mauris ut, commodo mauris. Proin leo risus, congue quis turpis vitae, sagittis pulvinar ipsum. Aliquam tempor sapien ipsum, non iaculis mauris accumsan ut. Nullam dapibus ligula eu ante pellentesque, eget tristique ligula sodales. Quisque eleifend massa nec erat blandit aliquet.

      Phasellus consequat turpis hendrerit, venenatis dolor id, pharetra metus. Proin interdum vestibulum urna, rutrum dapibus mauris dapibus a. Cras scelerisque massa non nisi tempus porta. Nullam faucibus a nunc eget aliquet. Duis auctor purus et commodo porttitor. Quisque et commodo turpis. Duis tristique convallis sem, id ultrices diam elementum sed. Nullam adipiscing, nunc eget ornare molestie, turpis sapien luctus lectus, sed vestibulum sapien urna a justo. Curabitur at eros non nulla ornare porttitor. Curabitur ac tortor blandit, dapibus risus dictum, aliquam ligula. Nunc ultrices faucibus nibh, vel sagittis tortor mollis convallis. Ut pretium tortor id pellentesque hendrerit. Aliquam erat volutpat.
      <!--<div id="_prcButtons">
        <input type="button" id="_proceed" class="btnConfirm" title="Answer the question" value="I wholeheartedly agree">
        <input type="button" id="_rd" class="btnConfirm" title="Redirect to Google" value="I strongly disagree">
      </div>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/et3sg/) 
I hope someone can help me with this.

Cheers!

Comment: Do I really have to? That's the only markup I have.

Comment: Not able to understand what do u mean by vertically centred div.

Comment: A parent div that's equal in margin top and bottom. Besides, I don't know how to add Bootstrap in jsFiddle.

Comment: Do u want ? 

HTML5 JavaScript CSS
Vertically and Horizontally Center With Twitter Bootstrap (Responsive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for some thing like this

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/et3sg/1/)

```
html, body, .container {
    height: 100%
}
.container {
    display: table;
}
.row {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what's happening here? Instead of using the Bootstrap's predefined classes, I changed their names and added them to the respective elements.

Comment: I'll suggest not to add any CSS for Bootstrap's predefined classes. You can add height:100% to body and html but for .container and .row create your own class and apply the above CSS it will work. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/et3sg/2/

Comment: Yea. That's what I meant. Seriously. Thank you for this! :)

Answer (score 0):

CHeck this if this worked ? `#home {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
      }`

or in css u can do by this :

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Working example here :  http://jsbin.com/sociloke/2/edit

Comment: This didn't work. I think that's for vertically centering contents.

Comment: Do u want ? [http://html5devgal.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/vertically-and-horizontally-center-with-twitter-bootstrap-responsive/](http://html5devgal.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/vertically-and-horizontally-center-with-twitter-bootstrap-responsive/)

Comment: This looks promising. However, are vertically centered divs not vertically centered responsively?

Comment: yeah these are different, you can use transform : http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-responsive-centered-image/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3ZepD/1/

Use the `table-cell` and `vertical-align`.

For better understanding I've added `height`, you can remove it.

Comment: Really? I see 600px yellow div with smaller content which is vertically centered. It was what you wanted, isn't it?

Comment: I need the div to be vertically centered, not the content.

Comment: Sure, without width declaring the parent div (.row) has the same height as its children - there is no different between centered and non-centered element, in both cases the children position is the same.

Comment: the row class is being extended in your solution. I might use it in another page or two that doesnt need vertical center alignment.

Comment: So you need to differ this page from the others, let´s say by ID on body (and then `#your_body_id .row {...}`). Or in small JavaScript in this page only: `<script>document.getElementById('home').parentNode.style.height = '600px';</script>`.